# Calculate the total charge

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm previewing this chapter and I'm completely new to this. How do I solve for the answer? Can someone also please explain those $t<0 & t>=0$? I don't get time less than 0.

[image]

[image]

From Nilsson and Reidel, Electric circuits 9th edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T stands for time.  I = 0 at T < 0 means that there is no current up until T = 0.  Put another way, it specifies the initial conditions.

Starting at T = 0, the current is a decaying exponential.  To solve this, remember that charge is the integral of current.